# XQuery - How do I extract a substring before the second occurrence of a character?

Tags: xslt, xquery, tokenize

Let's say I have this string: "123_12345_123456"

I would like to extract everything before the second "_" (underscore)

I tried:

```
fn:tokenize("123_1234_12345", '_')[position() le 2]
```

That returns:

```
123
1234
```

What I actually want is:

```
123_1234
```

How do I achieve that?

I am using XQuery 1.0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Regular expressions are flexible and compact:

```
replace('123_1234_12345', '_[^_]+$', '')
```

Another solution that may be better readable is to a) tokenize the string, b) keep the tokens you want to preserve and c) join them again:

```
string-join(
  tokenize('123_1234_12345', '_')[position() = 1 to 2],
  '_'
)
```

Comment: Awesome! I tested this and it works, thanks a lot.

Comment: Note that the `replace` expression above returns everything before the **last** `_`, not necessarily the **2nd** one as requested. If the input string always has exactly 3 occurrences of the `_` character, then it makes no difference - but the question specified a different logic.

Comment: That's a good point. For now it seems suitable for the current situation, but your solution has a more dynamic approach which is more future proof I would assume.

Comment: One more regex solution if you possibly have more than two `_` characters: `replace($input, '(.*_.*)_.*', '$1')`

Answer (score 1):

Taking the basic idea from Michael Kay's deleted answer, it could be implemented like this:

```
substring($input, 1, index-of(string-to-codepoints($input), 95)[2] - 1)
```